# Inserting data into 3 tables in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

Basically I have a site with a tag-it system similar to the one on this site, my table structures are as follows

```
TOPICS      TOPIC_TAGS    TAGS
topic_id    tag_id        tag_id
topic_data  topic_id      tags
```

Now what I am trying to do is run a series of queries so that when a TOPIC is posted, it enters the relevant topic data into the topic table(currently working), puts the tags into the tags table(currently working), then puts the tag_id from the TAGS table into the TOPIC_TAGS table in rows with the linked topic_ids(not working currently)

Right now it's not entering the tag_ids into the topic_tags like it does the tags table, it's just entering the LAST tags info into the row and not storing the associated topic_ids

Here is my code

```
$tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : null;

if (is_array($tags)) {
foreach ($tags as $t) {
    // Checking duplicate
     $sql_d = "SELECT * from tags where tags='$t'"; 
      $res=mysql_query($sql_d);
      $res = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($res<1)
    {
    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES('$t')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
 }
} else {
echo 'Invalid tag';
}

$tag_id = isset($_POST['tag_id']) ? $_POST['tag_id'] : null;

if (is_array($tag_id)) {
foreach ($tag_id as $tid) {

    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO topic_tags (tag_id) VALUES('$tid')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO topic_tags (tag_id)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$topic_data= htmlentities($_POST['topic_data']);
$posted_by = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$posted = "date_add(now(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)";
$invisipost = isset($_POST['invisipost']) ? $_POST['invisipost'] : 0 ;

if (($topic_data=="")) 
echo "<h2>Opps...</h2><p>You did not fill out all the required fields.</p>";

else 
$sql="INSERT INTO topics(topic_data, posted_by, posted, invisipost)VALUES('$topic_data', '$posted_by', $posted, $invisipost)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){

$sql="INSERT INTO topic_tags (topic_id)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE topic_tags.tag_id='". $_GET['tags'] ."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

**EDIT**

Would I be better to add the topics data first, then the tags, then the topic_tags info??

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert into `topic_tags` in one step in your 'foreach' loop. The last query

```
$sql="INSERT INTO topic_tags (topic_id)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE topic_tags.tag_id='". $_GET['tags'] ."'"
```

is neither insert nor update and it is definitely wrong

(edit)
so most likely you need something in the lines of the below:

```
foreach ($tag_id as $tid) {

    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO topic_tags (topic_id,tag_id) VALUES($topic_id,$tid)";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I'm still very new to mysql/php so my code probably looks like crud, I wasn't sure what I am doing wrong so hoping for some direction, thank you for your input.

Comment: you are dealing with many to many relation between topics and tags here. after update I don't see topic_id being fetched in the code and you will need topic_id in this context to create entries for each tag in topic_tags table

Comment: I removed the "where" part and it's inserting the LAST keywords ID into topic_tags, and it's putting the topic_id in a separate row.


 
topic_id  tag_id
0         3
1         0

Comment: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in"  foreach ($tag_id as $tid) {

Comment: Added additional question to my open post.

Comment: I don't know what is being returned by your request here and most likely the $tag_id array is for some reason empty hence 'Invalid argument...' error

Comment: yeah I am still quite new to both php and mysql, it's probably something simple I am not seeing, I am going to look to see if I can find any tutorials or guides on a many-to-many structure and see if anything clicks.